# Open3D ERROR: GLFW Error: WGL: Failed to make context current: The requested transformation operation is not supported

Tags: python, point-clouds

I am trying to visualize some pointcloud data in Open3d in Python, the screen renders the visualizer but as soon as I try to interact with it, it crashes with the above message.

```py
    import open3d as o3d
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(test_coords)
    o3d.io.write_point_cloud("oakland.ply",pcd)

    pcd_load = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("oakland.ply")
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd_load])
```

I couldn't really understand any of the reasons of why it's happening or how to fix this online.

Comment: The problem does not persist in Linux, so I think it is a windows only problem as well.